# Is it a proper implementation of external ngx-bootstrap module?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

is there any better way to outsource the ngx-b modules from AppModule than mine? can I use one array for both import and export ngx-b modules?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';

const bootstrapModulesI = [
  AlertModule.forRoot(),
  BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
  TabsModule.forRoot(),
  CollapseModule.forRoot()
];

const bootstrapModulesE = [
  AlertModule,
  BsDropdownModule,
  TabsModule,
  CollapseModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    bootstrapModulesI
  ],
  exports: [
    bootstrapModulesE
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class BootstrapModule { }
```

Comment: Does this work? You are importing and exporting arrays ?

Comment: yah this is working, but i am asking if there is any better approach?